# Passport local strategy working with postman, but not with axios, "missing credentials" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, passport.js

i'm trying to build a login system with passport and a local strategy. But whenever i try to run the request through axios it does not work, where as with postman the request works.

I get "missing credentials" as error with axios.

here is my axios request :

```
//api.js

localAuth: (username, password) => {
        console.log("running query")
        axios({method: "POST", url: "http://localhost:8080/login", data: {username: username, password: password}, withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log("Res = ", res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            if (!err.response) {
                // network err
                console.log('err: Network err');
            } else {
                console.log(err.response.data.message);
            }
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
```

Here is my local Strategy :

```
//passport.js


var options = {
    passReqToCallback: false,
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'Password'
};

passport.use(new localStrategy(options, (username, password, done) => {
            this.userHelper.isAuthenticated(username, password)
            .then(async (response) => {
                var user = {username: response.username, id: response.id};
                var res = {user: user, token: this.getToken(user), type: type};
                var token = await this.tokenHelper.saveToken(res)
                return done(null, token)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("an error occured : ")
                if (err === false) {
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Username or password'})
                }
                else {
                    console.log("stratgy error:", err)
                    return done(err, false);
                }
            })
        }))
```

and here is my server side request :

```
//app.js

app.post('/login', (req, res, done) => {
    strategy.authenticate('local',{session:true}, (err, user, info) => {
        console.log("err = ", err, " user = ", user, " info = ", info)
        if (err) {
            console.log("error occuring in local authentification strategy")
            res.send({sucess: false, message: err})
        }
        else if (!user) {
            console.log("error occuring in local user")
            res.send({sucess: false, message: "Unknown user or wrong Password"})
        }
        else {
            console.log("sucess on authorization")
            res.send({sucess: true, message: "Authorization suceeded"})
        }
    })(res, res);
})
```

The log of the callback variables of strategy.authenticate : `err =  null  user =  false  info =  { message: 'Missing credentials' }`

and finally here is the result of postman : `{"sucess":false,"message":"Unknown user or wrong Password"}`

[image: postman request configuration]

I've already set usernameField and passwordField, and since i'm using express 6.x.x I don't need to init bodyParser as it's done automatically via express.

Do you guys have any idea on what I'm missing ?

Comment: Can you show the full error and HTTP code or a stacktrace if the error source is axios?

Comment: not really, it's not an error, but the problem is that, when I do passport.use(new localStrategy ...) there is a done callback. This callback let me get info on what happened like if it suceeded or not and an optional message. The problem is when I try to Auth, I get "missing credentials" in the info value (check app.js) which I did not setup, so it's a passport one and I can't understand why it's triggered instead of the the ones I actually written.

Answer (score 0):

By default `axios` sends data in JSON format, so you should use one of the official ways described in the [official documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)
For instance:

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('username', username);
params.append('password', password);

axios({method: "POST", url: "http://localhost:8080/login", params, withCredentials: true
})
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm trying this out

Comment: I tried this method, and many others form the documentation, but none seems to be working, and once i'm using the URLSearch params one, the req.body is empty server side, I've tried by copying your code, the code of the documentation, but it's still empty

Comment: Can you compare the whole request along with its body in both cases?

Comment: here is the code of the auth : https://imgur.com/bx7t7FJ  followed by the results of the requests, the first request is the one made by axios with empty body, while the second one is the one made by postman: https://imgur.com/PKE01mF It seems that the credentials are still missing even with postman

Comment: Can you show request header and body in both cases (poatman and axios)?

Comment: Here it is : https://pastebin.com/GRqnnVV1

Comment: Please get axios request headers and body from browser dev tools, Network tab and postman request headers and body from the Postman itself

Comment: Sorry, here is the header from browser devtools : https://pastebin.com/hvwVwZ4Q And there from postman : https://imgur.com/cvq0lw8

Comment: I don't see `Content-Type` in axios headers, that' strange. And you didn't show bodies of both requests

Comment: Please add headers and bodies and the actual code with URLSearchParams in the post